# Dell Optiplex 980 Mini-Form Factor will not boot to Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, boot, bios, motherboard, cmos

I'm getting CMOS battery errors so I replaced the CMOS battery twice with new ones, loaded the BIOS defaults, cleared CMOS using the jumper (explained in the user manual) and put the hard drive into another machine and it booted fine in safe mode.

After replacing the CMOS battery I'm getting this message: "The system management requires a reset.  System startup configuration and the date time require attention after the reset.  I checked the logs and I keep getting the same 3 messages there all about the CMOS: cmos battery failure, cmos checksum error and cmos time not set.

It will not boot to windows 7, nor can I boot off the windows 7 setup cd in the cd rom drive.

I'm guessing it's the motherboard, but how do I confirm this or have I already done enough to ensure that is the problem?

Comment: Your computer is (more or less) 14 years old. A serious hardware error may well be unfixable or not worth the cost.

Comment: Yeah I think it's the motherboard, so I'll scrap it.

Comment: Try booting a 32-bit OS *from USB*  such as Debian, antiX, Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (which can be upgraded to 18.04 LTS after install), etc., https://www.debugpoint.com/32-bit-linux-distributions/ , before discarding the PC.